# Distinct count of string values from separate tables (coverage heat map)

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a coverage heat map of sorts in powerbi. I have 2 tables (Hourly Coverage and Weekly coverage) that I am trying to create a matrix from that will show the number of unique values for a certain time on a certain day.

Hourly Coverage table sample [image]

Weekly Coverage table sample  [image]

I have tried reconfiguring the tables to both have a technician column, transposed both to have the technicians as the column headers and the days/hours as the rows. I have thought about lookups, distinctcounts, selectcolumns, and other dax functions but can't figure it out. I am getting stuck at it counting the technicians per hour. Currently it is showing the technicians per day.

Matrix Example [image]

Matrix attributes

[image]

I'm sure this is complicated, but would appreciate any help. I would like to stay away from making multiple other tables for each day so that these 2 tables can easily be updated and kept up, and the matrix will auto-populate the correct values in the hour and day.